# What do you call someone who has a disease or mental condition?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun to suffix to a condition to refer to the person who has that condition.

Existing words are like:

> Cancer **patients** are subject to chemotherapy which causes them to lose their hair.

The problem with *patient* is that a patient is someone in the care of a health service, whereas I'm wanting to refer to people who are living with that condition in general.

> **Suffererers** of depression often find that they can not get themselves out of bed in the morning, they feel paralysed.

*Sufferer* is a loaded term, I don't want to imply that living with the condition is a negative experience.

Comment: The phrase *person with x* is often used.

Comment: @bib - I think that's actually a reasonable answer - you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase *person with x* or *person dealing with x* is often used. The terms  *patient, victim, sufferer* and the like all have a significantly negative and helpless connotation that many of us reject. Even *survivor* is tinged with victimhood that many reject.

We are not defined by our diseases, but are people who happen to be living with (and managing) them.

Comment: This is the term I'm ending up using.

Answer (score 6):

I would go with ***afflicted***.

As a verb, **to distress with mental or bodily pain; trouble greatly or grievously**.

- *to be afflicted with arthritis*

As a noun, **person or persons in constant suffering of body or mind**.

- *the afflicted often suffer in silence*

Answer (score 4):

You could try: "Those/People ***diagnosed*** with 'x'..."

Answer (score 0):

In the psychology world these days there is a movement towards something called " person-first language". Just as the term sounds, you refer to the person first before the disability. Instead of saying a "mentally ill person", or "the mentally ill", you would say " a person with bipolar disorder", or " person with a mental disorder". You are first acknowledging that said person is in fact a human being first, who happens then to be dealing with a disability of some kind. Sorry this is late.

“The difference between the right word and the almost right word is the difference between lightning and the lightning bug.” – Mark Twain